# How to filter a list in VueJS with multiple watchers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first time using VueJS. I am trying to build a page which displays data on the right and has several controls (checkboxes, drop downs, input text) on the left. The data on the right will be filtered when the controls on the left are selected/entered.

I'm trying to prepare a small demo for this on JSBin with dummy data: http://jsbin.com/qujaraf/edit?html,js,console,output

I have some data and I have two watchers `codesearch` and `typesearch`.

**Questions**

1. I would like the list to be filtered when I type stuff in them.
2. How can I make it so that when data is entered in both watchers then the filter takes both inputs in account. For example, in this demo, if user enters `actor` in `type` and `three` in `code` then only one list item should show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/huteyasuto/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
data: {
     typesearch: '',
     codesearch: '',
     processingmsg: 'waiting for you...',
     items: [
       {name: 'Stackoverflow', type: 'development', code: "one"},
       {name: 'Game of Thrones', type: 'serie', code: "two"},
       {name: 'Jon Snow', type: 'actor', code: "three"}
     ],
    filteredItems: [
       {name: 'Stackoverflow', type: 'development', code: "one"},
       {name: 'Game of Thrones', type: 'serie', code: "two"},
       {name: 'Jon Snow', type: 'actor', code: "three"}
     ]
  },

  // trigger filter on either input
  watch: {
    typesearch: function () {
      this.processingmsg = "processing type...";
      this.filteredItems = this.filterItems()
    },
    codesearch: function () {
      this.processingmsg = "processing code...";
      this.filteredItems = this.filterItems()
    }
  },

  // filter the list based on typesearch, then on codesearch               
  methods: {
    filterItems: function() {
      return this.items.filter(item => {
         return (
           (item.type.indexOf(this.typesearch.toLowerCase()) > -1)
         );
      }).filter(item => {
        return (item.code.indexOf(this.codesearch.toLowerCase()) > -1)
      })
    }
  }
```

Markup changes:

```
<div v-for="item in filteredItems" >
  <p>{{item.name}}<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I am trying to make sense of it. Is there a reason you've made two copies of the data (`items` or `filteredItems`)?

Comment: I don't know how to reference the original copy in the data declaration, otherwise I would. If you don't copy, you will initially have an empty list, since the view is now referencing the filtered list. In the real world, you won't be using an array literal anyway, so both lists would reference the variable that represents the data.

Comment: Yes, in the real world my data will be coming from the server as an API call. So in that case this would work ok?

Comment: This is a very simple implementation. I would not use this exactly as it is for production, but this is good for learning.

Comment: Using a computed would be a better way to go here.

Comment: I'm following the example from here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers I decided to use watchers because of that example. In my production case I'll be making calls to my backend API when user enters text for each control. The filtering would be done by my backend which would just return a JSON based on the search terms.

Comment: You'll definitely want to use the `_.debounce` method they show in that example if you will be using your API, so that you don't flood it with requests every time you type a single character

Comment: @Anthony If the filtering is done server side I don't understand the point of the question. If you are filtering client side, use a computed value. If you are filtering server side, you just need code that submits the API call.

Comment: What if I have multiple filters in an array and want to apply them in a loop? e.g [{key: 'city', val: 'San Francisco'}, {key: 'salary', val: '50000'}]